# Receiving Document ID Error on Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to automate an email that would send out charts located on multiple pages of my Google Sheets. It runs for the sheets named 'Issue Resolved' and 'Issue Count'.

However, I have run into issues with the lines calling the sheets 'Customers Helped', 'Vehicles', and 'Wait Time'.

The error I keep receiving is:

**Exception: Service Spreadsheets failed while accessing document with id **
sendEmailWithChartImages    @ Email Ambassador Results.gs:28

Any idea on what is going wrong here? Here is the code:

```
function sendEmailWithChartImages() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  
  // Define the chart sheets and their respective chart names
  var chartData = [
    { sheetName: 'Issue Resolved', chartName: 'Issue Resolved Chart' },
    { sheetName: 'Issue Count', chartName: 'Issue Count Chart' },
    { sheetName: 'Customers Helped', chartName: 'Customers Helped Chart' },
    { sheetName: 'Vehicles', chartName: 'Vehicles Chart' },
    { sheetName: 'Wait Time', chartName: '# of vehicles & avg. wait Chart' }
  ];
  
  var recipientEmail = 'recipient@example.com';
  var subject = 'Chart Images in Email';
  var body = 'Please find the chart images below:<br><br>';
  
  for (var i = 0; i < chartData.length; i++) {
    var sheetName = chartData[i].sheetName;
    var chartName = chartData[i].chartName;
    
    var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
    
    // Check if the sheet exists and has charts
    if (sheet && sheet.getCharts().length > 0) {
      var chart = sheet.getCharts()[0]; // Assuming there's only one chart on the sheet
      
      // Generate a temporary file to store the chart image
      var imageFile = DriveApp.createFile(chartName, chart.getAs('image/png'));
      
      // Convert the chart image to JPEG format
      var jpegImage = chart.getAs('image/jpeg');
      var base64ImageData = Utilities.base64Encode(jpegImage.getBytes());
      
      // Create the data URI for the inline image
      var dataUri = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + base64ImageData;
      
      // Embed the image in the email body
      body += '<h2>' + chartName + '</h2>';
      body += '<img src="' + dataUri + '">';
      body += '<br><br>';
      
      // Delete the temporary image file
      imageFile.setTrashed(true);
    }
  }
  
  // Create a draft email with the chart images embedded in the body
  var draft = GmailApp.createDraft(
    recipientEmail,
    subject,
    '',
    {
      htmlBody: body
    }
  );
  
  // Send the draft email
  draft.send();
}
```

I have confirmed all privileges for Apps Script to access the sheet, write emails as me, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I put images into an email draft:

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Email Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
     <img src="cid:img0" style="margin:2px 5px 2px 0;" /><?= filename[0] ?><br />
     <img src="cid:img1" style="margin:2px 5px 2px 0;" /><?= filename[1] ?><br />
     <? for(var i = 0;i < values.length; i++) { ?>
        <br /><?= "Data" + Number( i + 1) + ': ' + values[i] ?>
     <? } ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

gs:

function sendEmails101(obj) {

```
  let imgObj = {};
  let fldr = DriveApp.getFolderById("");
  let files = fldr.getFilesByType(MimeType.JPEG);
  let n = 0;
  let names = ['die1.jpg', 'die2.jpg'];
  let filename = [];
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    let f = files.next();
    let index = names.indexOf(f.getName());
    if (~index) {
      imgObj[`img${n++}`] = f.getBlob();//creates the image object
      filename.push(names[index]);
    }
  }
  let htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(obj.row[obj.index['htmlFile']]);
  htmlTemplate.values = obj.row.slice(obj.index['Data0']);
  htmlTemplate.filename = filename;
  let html = htmlTemplate.evaluate().getContent();
  if (html) {
    if (obj.row[obj.index['operation']] == 'Create Draft') {
      GmailApp.createDraft(obj.row[obj.index['Recipients']], obj.row[obj.index['Subject']], '', { htmlBody: html, inlineImages: imgObj, replyTo: obj.row[obj.index['replyTo']] });
    } else {

      GmailApp.sendEmail(obj.row[obj.index['Recipients']], obj.row[obj.index['Subject']], '', { htmlBody: html, inlineImages: imgObj, replyTo: obj.row[obj.index['replyTo']] });//image object is used in inlineImages option
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, Cooper! I found out that it was an issue with the type of chart that was in the workbook. I changed it from a bar and line to a line graph and the code worked.

It's very strange that the formatting of all things would cause an issue. I will definitely use your method next time since it is much more streamlined.